# initialize a final list with objects and another list at the same time in JAVA?

Tags: java, arrays, list, arraylist, initialization

I have a constant final list that I want to initialize with some objects and I want to add a list at the same time, is this syntactically possible with Java?

```
 public static final List<String> MY_LIST = Arrays.asList(new String [] { "Java","Python","Lisp","C#"});

 public static final List<String> SUB_LIST = Arrays.asList(new String [] {
"Cobol","Pascal"});
```

Now is there a way to add `SUB_LIST` to `MY_LIST` while initializing `MY_LIST` along with the other objects?

In simple pseudo code way,

```
List A = {"obj1","obj2", addALL(List B)}
```

Thank you all. I finally went with this solution:

```
public static final List<String> MY_LIST = Collections.unmodifiableList(new ArrayList<String>(){{
addAll(Arrays.asList(new String [] {"Java","Python","Lisp","C#"}));
addAll(SUB_LIST);}});
```

Comment: There are no `constant`s in Java...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public static final List<String> MY_LIST = new ArrayList<String>() {{
    addAll(Arrays.asList(new String [] { "Java","Python","Lisp","C#"}));
    addAll(SUB_LIST);
}} ;

public static final List<String> SUB_LIST = Arrays.asList(new String [] {
        "Cobol","Pascal"});
```

Here you should explicitly to declare real type of List (ArrayList in this example).

Answer (score 2):

Only the reference to the list is final, not the list itself. You may actually want to make the list unmodifiable if you want to make sure it's not altered after initialisation.

One solution would be:

```
public static final List<String> SUB_LIST = Collections.unmodifiableList(
                                              Arrays.asList("Cobol","Pascal"));

public static final List<String> MY_LIST = Collections.unmodifiableList(
                                              buildMyList(SUB_LIST));

private static List<String> buildMyList(List<String> subList) {
  List<String> myList = new ArrayList<> ();
  Collections.addAll(myList, "Java", "Python", "Lisp", "C#");
  myList.addAll(subList);
  return myList;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Java 8 and streams you could do the following:

```
private static final List<String> SUB_LIST = Collections.unmodifiableList(
            Arrays.asList("2#3#1#0", "1#0#4#1", "9#2#5#0", "4#2#3#2", "1#1#2#1"));

private static final List<String> MY_LIST = Collections.unmodifiableList(
            Stream.concat(Stream.of("s1", "s2"), SUB_LIST.stream()).collect(Collectors.toList()));
```

This way you do not need to define helper methods.

Answer (score 0):

When you do Arrays.asList it return a ArrayList inner class inside Arrays class which not support addall functionality.So if you pass to ArrayList in collection framework you can add all your sublist

```
List<String> MY_LIST = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(new String[] { "Java", "Python", "Lisp", "C#" })) ;

            List<String> SUB_LIST = Arrays.asList(new String[] { "Cobol", "Pascal" });
            MY_LIST.addAll(SUB_LIST);
            System.out.println(MY_LIST);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a static block to set up your static final fields to make it more readable.

```
    public static final List<String> MY_LIST; 

    public static final List<String> SUB_LIST; 

    static {
    MY_LIST = new ArrayList<String> (Arrays.asList(new String[] { "Java",
            "Python","Lisp","C#"}));
    SUB_LIST = new ArrayList <String> (Arrays.asList(new String [] {"Cobol",
            "Pascal"}));
    MY_LIST.addAll(SUB_LIST);
    }
```